# "light_ws2812" library 10x slower than required (AVR C, ATMega328p int. 8Mhz)

Tags: avr, atmega328p, library, atmel-studio, ws2812b

So I'm trying to run some SK6812 (WS2812 clones) on a standalone ATMega328p.

The output signal is too slow! I define F_CPU as 8000000 (8Mhz), both in the code and in the Atmel Studio Symbols, but my signal is slow by a factor of 10. The LED is always white, instead of red as the code intends.

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 8000000UL // 8 MHz clock speed
#endif

#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#include "light_ws2812.h"

struct cRGB led[1];

int main(void)
{


    while(1)
    {
        led[0].r=25;led[0].g=00;led[0].b=0;    // Write red to array
        ws2812_setleds(led,1);
        _delay_ms(500);                         // wait for 500ms.

        //led[0].r=0;led[0].g=25;led[0].b=0;            // green
        //ws2812_setleds(led,1);
        //_delay_ms(500);

        //led[0].r=0;led[0].g=00;led[0].b=25;       // blue
        //ws2812_setleds(led,1);
        //_delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

---

**Fuses are l:0xA2, h:0xD9, e:0x07**. This should correspond to an internal 8Mhz clock (verified on B0 with oscilloscope). Here's what I get for a data signal on B4:

[image]

The data looks fine (00000000 for green, then 00011001 (25d) for red). However the period is about 12µs, but according to the SK6812 datasheet, the period must be 1.25µs ± 150ns:

[image]

There's not much to show on the schematic, but to be thorough:
[image]

<s>And like I said before, the intended header for data (D6) didn't output anything, so I had to use B4 since it was also broken out to a header.</s>(Connectivity issue, I figured it out)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you using library code? Or are you directly programming the chip yourself to get the hardware configured and operating correctly? This phrase, "according to the datasheet," bothers me. A datasheet is about the MCU. It tells you nothing about a library.

Comment: @jonk I'm using example code from the library, modified slightly to simplify troubleshooting (just commenting out those few lines). The datasheet is for the SK6812 LED, sorry if that wasn't clear, I'll edit it in. The library is made to drive the specific timing of those LEDs.

Comment: Setting #define F_CPU 8000000UL only calibrates the standard library busy loops. You have to flip the fuses when programming the AVR to select the clock source and frequency (also, do not forget the CLKDIV8 fuse!)

Comment: @Janka I've got the fuses set for 8Mhz:
"Fuses are l:0xA2, h:0xD9, e:0x07. This should correspond to an internal 8Mhz clock (verified on B0 with oscilloscope)"
Am I missing something more?

Comment: For the pin problem: Did you try to manually configure the pin as output and set its output level to high (i.e. DDRD |= (1<<PD6); PORTD |= (1<<PD6); )? For the speed problem you should verify, that the symbol you defined in atmel studio is really set to F_CPU=8000000UL and that there is no additional zero (80 MHz). Fuses seem to be right.

Comment: You do realise that 1.25usec is only 10 machine cycles at 8MHz? You might struggle to achieve a toggle at that rate even with hand crafted assembly.

Answer (score 1):

In Atmel Studio, doing a
`#define F_CPU 8000000UL`
at the beginning of `main.c` was not sufficient. I've gotten rid of that code, and created a Defined Symbol
`F_CPU=8000000UL`
under

> Toolchain>AVR/GNU C Compiler>Symbols.

I'm still not really sure why defining `F_CPU` before even calling the libraries was erroneous; even util/delay threw some warnings sometimes (if I had `F_CPU` as an Undefined symbol, I think).

Comment: A #define applies only to the file in which it is found.  For something to apply to a whole project it would typically be placed in a header file that all source files explicitly #include, either directly or as a result of being included by another header file that is.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is not correct. `#define A B` means "From now on, replace any A by B in the following code". Since `#include foo` means "Paste the content of file foo here", a `define` is valid also in files included after, and `defines` inside included files are valid in the current file below the `include` directive.

Comment: Actually, it is correct - as you've just agreed, it only applies in files where it is either stated or included (a process which as you explain literally includes the content of that file - thus inheriting anything defined or included before). The asker's self-alleged problem is because **it does not apply to other C/C++ source files** which do not state or include it. In the Arduino realm however there's some hidden mumbo jumbo like concatenating all the .ino files together into a single source to feed the compiler's pre-processor, which can lead to expectations of non-standard behavior.

Comment: However Peter Smith's comment above makes it questionable that this is even the cause of slow behavior; if it's the solution it may be that it causes the delay to become a no-op.  But it would be interesting what the actual output frequency achieved now is.  My guess is that it would still be wrong, but perhaps close enough to now work.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yup, the library I'm using does produce non-exact timing. [This site](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/528.php) actually describes the process, moreso than I've looked into, but they explain a 7:3 clock cycle ratio for a '1' and 3:7 for a '0' at 8MHz (1.25us). Haven't hooked up a scope to confirm, but it works nonetheless.